# Как сделать easing с определенным промежутком времени?

Tags: javascript, математика, формулы

Всем привет! Есть такие небольшие функции - easing'и. Они позволяют менять значения переменных по определенным правилам.

**Пример одной из них (взял с интернета)**

```
Math.linearTween = function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*t/d + b;
};
@t = время
@b = начальное значение
@c = разница между начальным и конечным состоянием
@d = продолжительность
```

Вопрос в чем: как работает эта продолжительность? Мне нужно менять *"opacity" (от 0 до 1)* у объекта в течение 10 секунд. Но выполняется такой переход за секунду-две.

Как пользоваться подобными функциями? Или как провести изменение переменной в течение *N* секунд?

Comment: А что Вам нужно конкретно? Запустить эту функцию или написать функцию, которая уменьшит значение от 0 до 1 за N времени?

Comment: @OlmerDale второй вариант.

Comment: а что Вы хотите анимировать?

Comment: @OlmerDale например: выход объекта слева направо в течение времени "t"

Comment: Нее.. Вы не поняли! Какой объект Вы хотите анимировать? Если это dom объект, то есть варианты с css. Если это dom объект которым нужно управлять из js, то тут есть два нативных варианта. Но если это какой-то собственный объект-сущность, то да, нужно написать именно функцию о которой Вы спрашиваете. И для того чтобы я дал точный и полезный ответ, мне нужны все подробности. Так что за объект?

Comment: @OlmerDale это игровой объект (персонаж, пули, ворота и т.д.), вплывающие менюшки.

Comment: Если Ваш уровень знаний не позволяет реализовать такую ерунду так долго, то возможно Вам лучше воспользоваться готовой библиотекой для анимации? А то просто после вопроса "как сдвинуть что-то" появятся вопросы "как сдвинуть несколько что-то", а потом "как двигать с различной инерцией" и иму подобное. Воспользуйтесь https://greensock.com/

Comment: @OlmerDale спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Типа Вас устраивает предложенный вариант или это ирония и Вы все же ждете ответ?

Comment: @OlmerDale нет, мне не подходит вариант с библиотекой) Я хочу понять, как делать такие функции, и мне хотелось бы услышать ответ, если это возможно)

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать через Jquery Animate?

Comment: @Yuri, я конечно не знаю на что способна jQ Animate, но возможно она не умеет анимировать кастомные объекты? А возможно автор хочет повысить свой уровень.. Я могу только второй вариант понять :)

Answer (score -1):

Если не отвлекаться на мелочи и сосредоточится только на коде анимации, то выглядеть это будет примерно так -

```js
class AnimationNode {
  constructor( target, propName, delay, from, to ){
    this.target = target;
    this.propName = propName;
    
    this.delay = delay * 1000;
    
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
  }
}

class MoveSystem {
  constructor(){
    this.nodeAll = [];
  }
  
  update( elapsedTime ){
    let length = this.nodeAll.length;
    
    for( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
      let node = this.nodeAll[ i ];
      
      let path = node.to - node.from;
      let coef = path / node.delay;
      let result = coef * elapsedTime;
      
      if( result > node.to ){
        result = node.to;
      }
      
      
      Object.assign( node.target.style, {
        [node.propName]: result + "px"
      } );
    }
  }
}

const systemAll = [ new MoveSystem() ];

function update( elapsedTime = 0 ){
  let length = systemAll.length;
  
  for( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
    systemAll[ i ].update( elapsedTime );
  }
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame( update );
}

update();

let rect = document.body.querySelector( '.rect' );

let node = new AnimationNode( rect, "left", 10, 0, 200 );
systemAll[ 0 ].nodeAll.push( node );
```

```css
.rect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: tomato;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```